# Is it possible for an Android app to use data from another app?

Tags: java, android, smartphone

I have never made an app before but I’m currently relearning Java with hopes to make an Android app soon. However a key part of my app would rely on borrowing data from another app, namely the Digital Wellbeing app by Google. I essentially want to build an app that will take user’s phone usage data and do cool stuff with it. Is this possible?

Comment: Generally, when an app collects data, there needs to be an API for sharing that data -- particularly if there are privacy concerns. It would probably be considered a security flaw if one app could access data within another app without permission. I would expect that the data collected by Google's Wellbeing app would need explicit permission from the user to share the data.

Comment: Okay so it’s possible as long as the user agrees to share the data?

Comment: That's not completely true. An API created by Google also needs to exist in order for you to access that data.

Comment: Okay, how do I check for the API?