# is it possible to program an app that receives data from an already existing app?

Tags: android, android-studio, data-sharing

I'm trying to program an app using *android studio* that receives data (blood sugar levels) from the app tomato (which calculates blood sugar levels automatically every 5 mins or so). The tomato app already exists and is made by a company.
So I was wondering **if doing this is possible. if so, how?**

I saw this post: [Is it possible for an Android app to use data from another app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58757522/is-it-possible-for-an-android-app-to-use-data-from-another-app) which is very similar to what im trying to do but i didnt find an exact solution/answer to this.

Any opinions and help are very much needed and welcomed.

Comment: The comments under the linked post basically answer your question: you can access the data if the other app exposes the data to you.

Comment: @luk2302 do you mean explicitly? like contacting the app owners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first need to know how the app is storing the data, you could check your phone's storage using the Device File Explorer in Android Studio. If they have exposed the data then you are able to check and read the files that the app has exposed. However, I have a feeling that they would not be leaving them in plain text for you to take.

Upon some further reading, it seems they read from a device called a MiaoMiao Transmitter. You could ask the producer of this product for a developer kit and see what they say. This would come with documentation as to how you can get data from the product. However, if they do not provide you with any help, you will need to do some investigation as to how the device functions.

Perhaps it sends android broadcasts when it is taking a reading? This is just speculation of course. This is very niche and I believe that is a reason there are only a few apps that use the device - they are trying to lock out "non-verified" developers. However, when there is a will, there is always a way! ;)

Best of luck!